# Why is the default .gitignore in Magento 2 ignoring files from /pub/media?

Tags: magento2.2, github

I want to version control my Magento 2 site project, it has lots of catalog images. All .gitignore templates I found online are excluding from /pub/media , why is that?

There are different cases where another developer might need the images also
Also, if I want to deploy to live server, lets say AWS EC2 using git, (pulling from the remote repo) the images would be missing.

Can the experts please give me some insight on this issue?

Comment: I think these images under /pub/media doesn't must save in repo. Process of development don't influence from these.

Comment: My gitignore simply - https://github.com/elevinskii/deepfish/blob/master/.gitignore

Comment: but if you dont save the images in repo (theme images and/or catalog images) , how is other developer work on the site without the images, if he needs them? Also if I deploy to live, by pulling from master, the site will be missing the catalog images

Comment: @EvgenyLevinsky your link is broken can you post again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are not **required** for a project to run, which should be the point for a **code** repository

Imagine a 200k sku's catalog with all catalog images inside git repository... what a size! https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80962/should-images-be-stored-in-a-git-repository

Isn't it easier to just download them from staging / production environments to local environment?